# Matrix fields within Zoo Visitor

Tags: matrix, zoo-visitor

At the moment I just want to display some data stored in a matrix field in the Zoo Visitor channel, but no data is shown. I am able to update native member data via Zoo Visitor.

My code at the moment (reduced template code):

```
# {billing_info} = Matrix field
# {billing_company_name} = text field within matrix
# {billing_reference} = text field within matrix
# {billing_company_vat} = text field within matrix

{exp:zoo_visitor:update_form 
    return='/account/edit/address/success'
    role='form'
    include_jquery='no'
    datepicker='no'
    include_assets='no'
    secure_action='yes'
    secure_return='yes'
    class='form-horizontal'
}
    {billing_info}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="billing_company_name" name="billing_info[billing_company_name]" placeholder="Company Name" value="{billing_company_name}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="billing_reference" name="billing_info[billing_reference]" placeholder="Reference" value="{billing_reference}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="billing_company_vat" name="billing_info[billing_company_vat]" placeholder="VAT No." value="{billing_company_vat}">
    {/billing_info}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
```

What am I doing wrong?
I am logged in on the page.

Tags like the ones below are working fine.

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details}
    {visitor:member_firstname}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

Currently running EE 2.9 + Zoo Visitor 1.3.32 + Matrix 2.6

Comment: Louis, can you change the name="" custom fields straight ([) brackets to curls ({)...

Comment: Hi Nutmeg, that wouldn't make any sense in this case because I'm only trying to read/load data from EE, it's not about posting at this point. It's about the code inside the value="{blabla}" param. I have tried it any way but no go :(

Comment: I have just tested a simple text field (not within a matrix field) and that works fine. Is there some known compatibility issue with Matrix, Zoo and EE 2.9 maybe?

Comment: This is strange. I created a new Matrix field and that one works fine... Can a Matrix field go corrupt?

Comment: OK, I not notice that the matrix field that is ordered as last (I have 4 matrix fields in that channel), is that one that displays the contents. The others don't display anything. That's why the new field I created did display data, as a newly created field is always added as the last field.

Comment: Did you check the template debugger with the first matrix tag? and has Zoo been updated recently to play nice with EE2.9?

Comment: Yes, there was nothing there. In the end I found my problem and posted the answer below.

Comment: To demonstrate my problem I even made a screen capture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vqg394fl1rhzsb/ScreenFlow.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after hours and hours of aggravation I followed the advice of the Zoo developer on the [Devot-ee forums](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/13745), where we did some more testing, to file a bug report with EE. I first did a bug search and [found my error](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20335/channel-form-problem-with-multiple-complex-fields-in-the-same-form)... If only I would have known this before.